# tf.keras.Model.load_weights() caught ResourceExhaustedError

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, resources

I have two ipynb files: `train.ipynb` and `predict.ipynb`. I have trained a model with fit generator(with batch size 64) in `train.ipynb` and caught `ResourceExhaustedError` when I tried to load weights in `predict.ipynb`
I'm using keras inside tensorflow v1.9 and tensorflow docker image.

```
# train.ipynb

def network():
    #[ A normal model]
    return model
model = network()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit_generator(seq,shuffle=True,
                    epochs = 10, verbose=1
                   )
# save the model and weight after training
with open('model.json','w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(model.to_json())
model.save_weights('model.h5')
clear_session() # tried to clear the session here
# saved both successfully
# model.h5(131MB)
```

After successfully saved, I can load it back inside `train.ipynb` However, when I do the same thing in `predict.ipynb`, an error is caught.

```
# train.ipynb
with open('model.json','r') as json_file:
    test_model = model_from_json(json_file.read())
test_model.load_weights('model.h5')
# No error here

# predict.ipynb
with open('model.json','r') as json_file:
    test_model = model_from_json(json_file.read())
test_model.load_weights('model.h5')
# Got the following error
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[28224,1024] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are you running both notebooks simultaneously? Your GPU is out of memory. Try `nvidia-smi` in the command line to check on your GPU's resource usage, although be aware that TensorFlow by default occupies all available GPU memory. `keras.backend.clear_session()` could be of help as well.

Comment: nope, I ran separately. And I have called clear_session() after save the model. See the code snippet above.